# What is RNN LSTM input shape supposed to be?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm confused about how LSTM input sizes work.

I have a scenario where im trying to predict the weight of a person based on weight and height, both in time series.

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong in terms of dimensions:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, LSTM, Input, concatenate
from keras.models import Model

def create_dataset(dataset, window_length=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-window_length-1):
        # print("dataX from {} to {}".format(i, i+window_length))
        # print("dataY from {}".format(i+window_length))
        dataX.append(dataset[i:(i+window_length)])
        dataY.append(dataset[(i + window_length):])


    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

def buildModel(dataLength, labelLength):

    weight = Input(shape=(dataLength, 1), name="weight")
    height = Input(shape=(dataLength, 1), name="height")

    weightLayers = LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)(weight)
    heightLayers = LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)(height)

    output = concatenate([ weightLayers, heightLayers ])

    output = Dense(labelLength, activation="linear", name="weightedAverage_output")(output)

    model = Model(
        inputs=[weight, height],
        outputs=[output]
        )

    model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="mse")

    return model

bogus = {
    "weight": range(100,200),
    "height": range(150,250)
}

dataset = pd.DataFrame(bogus)



train_size      = int(len(dataset) * 0.90)
test_size       = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test     = dataset[:train_size], dataset[-test_size:]

# print("*" * 30)
# print(train.head())
# print(train.tail())
# print("==> {}".format(len(train)))
# print("*" * 30)
# print(test.head())
# print(test.tail())
# print("==> {}".format(len(test)))
# input(">")

height_train = np.array(train["height"].values.tolist()).reshape((-1, 1)).astype('float32')
weight_train = np.array(train["weight"].values.tolist()).reshape((-1, 1)).astype('float32')

height_test = np.array(test["height"].values.tolist()).reshape((-1, 1)).astype('float32')
weight_test = np.array(test["weight"].values.tolist()).reshape((-1, 1)).astype('float32')

x_train_height, y_train_height  = create_dataset(height_train, 60)
x_train_weight, y_train_weight  = create_dataset(weight_train, 60)

x_test_height, y_test_height  = create_dataset(height_test, 60)
x_test_weight, y_test_weight  = create_dataset(weight_test, 60)



model = buildModel(60,4)
model.fit(
    [ 
        x_train_weight,
        x_train_height,
    ],

    [ 
        y_train_weight
    ],

    validation_data=(
        [
            x_test_weight,
            x_test_height,
        ],
        [
            y_test_weight
        ],
    ),

    epochs=1,
    batch_size=3000,
    callbacks=[
        # board.createTensorboardConfig("log/graph"),
    ]
)
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected weightedAverage_output to have shape (None, 4) but got array with shape (29, 1)

Pretty sure i'm going wrong somewhere in input and output dimensions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you do a model.summary() and post it here as well?

Comment: here you go: https://pastebin.com/5kPqgB1g

Comment: So as I can see, you need to reshape your output variable after concatenation of weight layers and heightlayer.

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: Can you  change this 'output = Dense(labelLength, activation="linear", name="weightedAverage_output")(output)' to 'output = Dense(1, activation="linear", name="weightedAverage_output")(output)
' and let me know if this is working?

Comment: i don't think that's right. Ran it anyway and got this error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected weight to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (0, 1)

Comment: I think it is right the other thing you need to define is timesteps. Refer this post: https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-timesteps-lstm-networks-time-series-forecasting/

Comment: output is a Dense layer object, not numpy array. can't reshape

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158564/discussion-between-bhushan-pant-and-taewoo).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change the dimension of your final output layer:

```
output = Dense(1, activation="linear", name="weightedAverage_output")(output)
```

Secondly, you need to change the input dimensions to include timesteps:

```
timesteps = 1
weight = Input(shape=(dataLength,timesteps,1), name="weight")
height = Input(shape=(dataLength,timesteps,1), name="height")
```

Timesteps can range between (0,inf).

You can refer this post for further knowledge on timesteps: https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-timesteps-lstm-networks-time-series-forecasting/

Comment: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Comment: What do you exactly mean by timesteps? Do you mean the lags that you want to consider? (I.e. the autoregeessive part) or do you mean timesteps in the sense of sequences of lagged-samples? NONE, NONE says what they mean, and most people use wrong terminology